No keystrokes are registered when booting into a disk with a boot selection menu/"Press any key to boot from CD/DVD" screen
On my mid-2011 iMac, when I try to boot into the Windows XP installation disk I have put into the Mac's disk drive, no keystrokes are registered however the keyboard is powered (the lights on it are on). This leads to XP skipping the boot into the install, as I cannot press anything to boot from the CD.
I've also noticed this issue for a GParted live disk I have. The GParted boot selection menu appears, however trying to use arrow keys, or pressing Enter, will simply not do anything. If I unplug the keyboard and then plug it back in again, the lights turn on and the countdown on the GParted boot menu... freezes? It freezes like this for about 3-4 seconds and then the countdown resumes as normal, however still no keyboard input detected.
I have also tried different USB ports for the keyboard and can confirm the keyboard works when booting into Windows 7 installed on the Hard Drive, and also works in the Windows 7 setup (which doesn't ask to press a key to boot from the DVD).
Why is it that no keystrokes are being registered when trying to boot into these disks?
Note: I cannot use Bootcamp due to the fact the Hard Drive has Windows 7 on it, and not OS X.

I found a fix, albeit a bit annoying. Delete Windows 7 off the hard drive so it has nothing else to boot to, and then run the XP installer. I would prefer a way to do this without deleting any other Windows OS, like maybe with grub-install and a custom config however I guess this is good enough. (I didn't even mean to delete Windows 7, it was a mistake when using GParted on an old Ubuntu disk, but I guess it kind of worked out in the end?)
